# Parsing issue in API's for Picasa in iOS

Tags: ios, api, picasa, google-api-objc-client

I am working with an iOS application in which I authenticate the user. While authentication process when I get GDataFeedPhotoAlbum , I did not get the nickname and the results says it is unparsed. Below is the output on my log.

```
 - GDataFeedPhotoAlbum : GDataFeedBase 0xa629130: {v:2.0
   etag:W/"C0UHQ3o4eSp7ImA9XRZUEkk." title:Saki subtitle:Created
   2014-08-05 12:20:32 +0000 rights:public updated:2014-08-05T12:20:32Z
   authors:1 categories:1 links:feed,alternate,slideshow,report,self
   id:https://photos.googleapis.com/data/feed/user/114789383162963173862/albumid/6044055072559797137
   unparsed : < gphoto:access > ,< gphoto:allowDownloads >,< gphoto:allowPrints >,<    gphoto:id >,< gphoto:location >,< gphoto:name >,< gphoto:nickname >,< gphoto:numphotos >,< gphoto:timestamp > ,< gphoto:user>}
```

How can I rectify this issue? Is there any way by which I can remove the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Nickname [is part of](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Source/Clients/Photos/GDataFeedPhotoAlbum.m#155) GDataFeedPhotoAlbum. I wonder if the GData Objective-C client library sources compiled into your app are so old that they lack all of the fields.